# how to Create Video using Image And mp3 file?

Tags: android, image-processing, video, video-processing

I want to Create video using Image and mp3 or m4a file. 
I try to use ffmpeg library but that library still not working for me.
I’m also try to use Media-codec and MediaMuxer.

if you have any new library or code then please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.